BECOME password после ввода пароля
Пытаюсь выполнить обновление сервера используя ansible, но возникли проблемы:
# ansible ALT_0d -b -m shell -a "apt-get dist-upgrade" --become-user=root -i /etc/ansible/hosts

На сервере ansible никаких процессов нет, после ввода пароля висит в состоянии:
BECOME password:

На клиенте в логах:
ansible-command[14964]: Invoked with _raw_params=apt-get dist-upgrade _uses_shell=True warn=False stdin_add_newline=True strip_empty_ends=True argv=None chd>

При запуске в ручную на клиенте команда отрабатывает успешно:
# apt-get dist-upgrade


Если установить обновления в ручную, а после снова через ansible, то команда отрабатывает:
server | CHANGED | rc=0 >>
Чтение списков пакетов...
Построение дерева зависимостей...
0 будет обновлено, 0 новых установлено, 0 пакетов будет удалено и 0 не будет обновлено.

Проблема решилась следующей командой:
ansible ALT_0d -b -m apt_rpm -a "update_cache=true dist_upgrade=true update_kernel=true clean=true" become-user=root -i /etc/ansible/hosts -v -K

